# Adding colors to objects in a loop

Tags: color

I'm just starting out in Mathematica and still learning the ropes.

I'm making a "necklace" which is a circle with squares around it. The following works:

```
necklace[n_] :=
 Block[    {minCenter, maxCenter, circ, center, squares, out}, (
   circ := Circle[{0, 0}, 10];
   center :=
    Table[    {10*Cos[k*2*Pi/n] , 10*Sin[k*2*Pi/n]  }  , {k, 1, n} ];
   minCenter := center - 0.5;
   maxCenter := center + 0.5;
   squares :=
    Table  [     
     Rectangle[ minCenter[[i]], maxCenter[[i]]    ] , {i, 1, n}    ];
   out := Graphics[{circ, {Red, squares}}];
   print["hi"];
   Return[out]
   )]
necklace[10]
```

The problem is that I want each square to have a different color, right now they're all red. But when I edit the out:= Graphics at the bottom, it will change every square. For testing I was using Randomcolor[] but 1 random color is assigned to the whole necklace instead of for each one. Do I need a table of colors? Multiple outs? What's the best way?

Comment: Welcome! Take a look at `Thread` or `Map` or `Riffle`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way to make a random necklace that uses much less code:

```
necklace[n_] := 
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 10], {RandomColor[], Rectangle[# - 1/2]}
 & /@ (10 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ (2 π Range[n]/n))}]

necklace[40]
```

[image]

Here's a rainbow-necklace generator:

```
necklace2[n_] := 
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 10], MapIndexed[{Hue[First@#2/n], 
 Rectangle[# - 1/2]} &, 10 {Cos@#, Sin@#} & /@ (2 π Range[n]/n)]}]

necklace2[40]
```

[image]

Comment: This is excellent thanks! Is there a cheatsheet on where I can find the meaning of those symbols?

Comment: @KevinDuke: If you search for `@` in the Documentation Center, you will get a link to `Prefix`, which explains that (for example) `f@a` is shorthand for `f[a]`. The `#`, `#2` and `&` are pure function notation, the details of which can be learned at the Documentation Center page for `Function`. Likewise, if you search the documentation for `/@` you will find that it is shorthand notation for `Map`, for example `f/@a` is `Map[f,a]`. All the other stuff is built-in, the details of which can be found in the docs. BTW, the documentation center is wonderful, it's how I learned the language.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
necklace[n_, colors_: {Red}] := 
Block[{minCenter, maxCenter, circ, center, squares, out, 
  colorslist}, (circ := Circle[{0, 0}, 10];
  center := Table[{10*Cos[k*2*Pi/n], 10*Sin[k*2*Pi/n]}, {k, 1, n}];
  minCenter := center - 0.5;
  maxCenter := center + 0.5;
  colorslist = Flatten[Nest[Append[colors, #] &, colors, Floor[n/Length[colors]]]];
  squares := 
  Table[{colorslist[[i]], 
  Rectangle[minCenter[[i]], maxCenter[[i]]]}, {i, 1, n}];
  out := Graphics[{circ, squares}];
  Return[out])
]
{necklace[20, {Red, Green, Blue}], necklace[20]}
```

Which yields a necklace with the colors specified (repeated). Default value is red

[image]

What I basically do, is to take the list of colors provided at execution of the command (or its default value a list with only Red) and repeat it several times until it is longer than the number of circles.

Edit:

If you want a colorchange, you can use colorfunctions. Use `Colordata[{schemename,{minValue,maxValue}}][value]` to color your rectangles. Then you have another solution: (as default we will take rainbow colors)

```
 necklaceCF[n_, colorsfunctionname_: "Rainbow"] := Block[{minCenter, maxCenter, circ, center, squares, out, 
  colorslist}, (circ := Circle[{0, 0}, 10];
  center := Table[{10*Cos[k*2*Pi/n], 10*Sin[k*2*Pi/n]}, {k, 1, n}];
  minCenter := center - 0.5;
  maxCenter := center + 0.5;
  squares := 
  Table[{ColorData[{colorsfunctionname, {1, n}}][i], 
  Rectangle[minCenter[[i]], maxCenter[[i]]]}, {i, 1, n}];
  out := Graphics[{circ, squares}];
  Return[out])]
{necklaceCF[20], necklaceCF[20, "FruitPunchColors"]}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, thanks a lot! Sort of a separate question but let's say I wanted a gradient of colors where the first color is red, last purple, while compensating for the size of the necklace. What else would have to be done to do this?

Comment: Since you seem new to SE, when an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer to credit it.